# Multitouch on Dell Inspiron 7537

Tags: dell, touchpad, multi-touch, trackpad, touchegg

Has anyone been able to get trackpad multitouch gestures working with a Dell Inspiron 7537? I've tried synclient to change values in Synaptics config but not having much luck.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and haven't had much luck with touchegg or modifying Synaptics config with synclient. Two finger scrolling works fine but I'm looking for a few other features (3-finger swipe for workspaces, palm sensitivity, one-finger click/hold and second-finger drag --- similar to OSX functionality on Macbook Pros).

I've read through a couple of similar postings here but haven't had much luck with implementation.

Looking to see if someone has specifically had any luck on the same platform (7537)...

Thanks

Comment: Please, confirm this bug here about the drag bug.
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with my Asus Zenbook. To fix the 3-finger swipe I had to activate the Desktop Wall plugin in CCSM. For some reason it was deactivated by default. My setup (4-finger swipe) for scale windows (super-key + w) didn't work either, instead it just showed the dash (super-key). To fix it I had to change the shortcut for the dash to something different. I guess they made some hidden changes in 14.04 compared to 13.10.